# "Jqgrid loadoncomplete" trigger a javascript from an external file

Tags: jqgrid

I am using Firefox 37.x, jqGrid : 4.7.0 , jQuery : v1.11.2

Process : Grid creation parameters

```
datatype:"json",
jsonReader:{root:'rows',page:'page',total:'total',records:'records', userdata: "userdata",cell:'cell',id:'id'},
loadComplete:urlxdatafetch,
mtype:'GET',
hidegrid:false,
loadonce:true,
....
```

Can `loadComplete` trigger an external JavaScript function from an external js file?

loadComplete: urlxdatafetch()

Answer (score 1):

There are many options to do what you want. The best choice depend on *what you plan to do inside of `urlxdatafetch` function.

jqGrid supports callbacks and jQuery events. So you can either use *one* callback function `loadComplete` or to use *any number* of `jqGridLoadComplete` or `jqGridAfterLoadComplete` event handlers. jqGrid triggers first `jqGridLoadComplete` event, then it execute `loadComplete` callback and finally it triggers `jqGridAfterLoadComplete` event.

I would recommend you to use `jqGridLoadComplete` or `jqGridAfterLoadComplete` event in external JavaScript file because you will have the mostly scalable solution in the case. I explain below how to use there. I will use `jqGridLoadComplete`, but the same works exactly so in case of usage `jqGridAfterLoadComplete`. Let us you have `<table id="grid"></table>` on the page and you use jqGrid to convert it to the grid. So you can use

```js
$("#grid").bind("jqGridLoadComplete", function (e, data) {
    alert("jqGridLoadComplete is triggered for #grid");
});
```

It's important to understand that you can make such binding either after the grid is created (using `$("#grid").jqGrid({...});`) or **before it's created**. The recommended way is to make bindings *before* the grid is created, because it's the only way which guarantee, that the event handler will be executed even for the first time directly answer creating the grid. If you use `datatype: "local"` for example then the grid will be filled directly during creating and the callback `loadComplete` (and the events `jqGridLoadComplete` or `jqGridAfterLoadComplete`) will be executed immediately. So, if it would be important don't miss the first filling of the grid, then you could make binding before the grid is created.

If you would do prefer to use `loadComplete` then you should use the form

```js
loadComplete: urlxdatafetch
```

(not as `loadComplete: urlxdatafetch()`) and you need to define `urlxdatafetch` function **as global function**:

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
    function urlxdatafetch (data) {
        alert("loadComplete is triggered for #" + this.id);
    }
</script>
```

Another common pattern is to define **one** global object like `jQuery` or `$` and to set all global functions or global variables as methods/properties of your global object.

For example I develop a solution under the same MyProject. So I create one JavaScript file `MyProject.common.js` which I include after `jquery.jqgrid.min.js` in all pages of my solution:

```html
<script src="MyProject.common.js"></script>
```

Inside of the `MyProject.common.js` I defined global object `MyProject` and some other

```js
(function ($) {
    "use strict";
    window.MyProject = {
        urlxdatafetch: function (data) {
            alert("loadComplete is triggered for #" + this.id);
        }
    };
}(jQuery));
```

inside of other JavaScript file I create jqGrid and use `loadComplete: MyProject.urlxdatafetch` as the parameter. In the way one have **only one** global variable `MyProject` and you have no name conflicts with another JavaScript files and jQuery plugins which you include on the page.

It's recommended to include in the `MyProject.common.js` file setting of default values of jqGrid parameters to make later crating of the grid more short, readable and easy to maintain. I recommend you to examine the default values of jqGrid options described in [the documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:options). You will see that the values of `jsonReader` and `mtype` are already default and you can skip there. The values of `datatype`, `hidegrid` and `loadonce` can be set in the way

```js
(function ($) {
    "use strict";
    window.MyProject = {
        urlxdatafetch: function (data) {
            alert("loadComplete is triggered for #" + this.id);
        }
    };
    $.extend(true, $.jgrid.defaults, {
        datatype: "json",
        hidegrid: false,
        loadonce: true,
        height: "auto",
        gridview: true,
        autoencode: true,
        headertitles: true,
        ignoreCase: true,
        loadui: "block",
        scrollrows: true
    });
}(jQuery));
```

I included above some common settings. You can define in the way default callback functions too. After setting such defaults you can reduce the code which you use on page of your project.